# wrong Button textColor and drawablePadding on pre-Lollipop using Appcompat

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat

I have wrong button style on pre-Lollipop devices.

compiling using appcompat library.

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>

    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>

</style>

<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
</style>
```

v21/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="ButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The result is http://prntscr.com/8mt1jx

"New button" adding by xml on ISC has no style textColor and drawablePadding. Do you have any ideas to correct it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `buttonStyle` in your normal styles.xml.

Replace

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
```

With

```
<item name="buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 1):

So for pre-Lollipop devices work this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>

    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonProgramAddTheme</item>

</style>

<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>

</style>

<style name="ButtonProgramAddTheme" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>

</style>
```

The result is: http://prntscr.com/8mtoqa

Also for the same view of the program add buttons we can add custom background by selector, because AppCompat does not in fact support the Button widget on pre-Lollipop devices.